How to configure multipass istance so that it can connect to router/gateway on the host subnet?
I'm newbie to multipass.
I've succesfully created an Ubuntu 24.04 LTS instance using:
multipass launch --name test

I've noted that the instance acquire an IP address on a subnet like 172.16.xxx.xxx
Anyway my host PC and my router/gateway are on a different subnet : 192.168.1.xxx
For this reason, I think, the instance can't access to Internet.
The question is:
how may I configure the istance so that it can retrieve internet parameters from the DHCP server that runs on my PC/router network (192.168.1.xxx)?
Any idea?
Thanks in advance
